# Type Casting in swift

Tags: swift, casting

I am bit confused with typecasting in Swift.

Have a small doubt.
What is the difference between `as?`,`as!` and only `as`.
And can we say "as" is similar to `is`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please search first. This has been satisfactorily explained many times already. Even better, learn Swift.

Comment: Yes,I have searched and i got answers on "as?" and "as!" but not only "as"

Comment: `as` is used for casting when it is guaranteed to succeed (String to NSString, [AnyObject] to NSArray, etc.)

Comment: Then whats the difference between "as" and "as!"

Comment: `as!` is used if it cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 'as' keyword is used for casting.

'as' example:

```
let calcVC = destinationViewController as CalculatorViewController
```

This line casts the destinationViewController to a CalculatorViewController.  However, this would crash if destinationViewController was not a CalculatorViewController or a subclass thereof.

To protect against a crash, you can use 'if let' with 'as?'...

'as?' example:

```
if let calcVC = destinationViewController as? CalculatorViewController {
   // ... write code to execute if destinationViewController is in fact a CalculatorViewController
}
```

You can even check before you even try to do 'as' with the 'is' keyword...

'is' example:

```
if destinationViewController is CalculatorViewController {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,Nice explanation. But still not clear about only "as" .                         I tried `var button = somebutton as UIButton` and it was throwing an error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Is somebutton an instance of type UIButton or a subclass of UIButton?  If not then an error will be thrown.  You can only cast one object to a certain class if it is an instance of that class or an instance of a subclass.

Answer (score 4):

`is` is used to check the type of a value whereas `as` is used to cast a value to a different type.

The conditional form, `as?`, returns an optional value of the type you are trying to downcast to.

Example:

```
let number: Int = 1 
if number as? Int {
print ("Int")
}
```

You are "asking" if number is of type Int.

Using the `as!` you're forcing, for example, your let number to be of a certain type, in case it is not, a crash you're going to take!

Example:

```
if number as! String { //CRASH

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer in simple words ->

as! -> it is used for casting one data type to other data type forcefully(Use this only if you are sure..). We even call it force downcast means we downcast a particular type from superclass to subclass.

as -> This keywprd is used to raise an object to superclass type. So in other words we can say its upcasting.

as? -> So in this case unless you are certain that this cast is going to work then better option to add ? instead of !. Its also downcasting.